# What is the full and correct way to formally/logically state the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, and its negation?

Tags: logic, notation, definition, predicate-logic, epsilon-delta

Is this an accurate and correct way to represent the epsilon-delta definition in full?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0,\ \exists \delta > 0,\ \forall x,\ (0< |x-a|  < \delta) \rightarrow (|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon)$$

(even if it's just a little bit off or inaccurate I'd like to know what the correct version is).

I was also unsure what it looks like negated because of the if-and-only-if piece. So far I have it to

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \neq L \Leftrightarrow \exists \varepsilon > 0,\ \forall \delta > 0,\ \exists x,\ (0< |x-a|  < \delta) \land (|f(x) - L| \geq \varepsilon)$$

What's the correct way to state the definition as well as its negation?
 How do you negate the if-and-only-if piece here? Because $a \Leftrightarrow b = (a \rightarrow b) \land (b \rightarrow a)$ so negating it would mean $(a \not\rightarrow b) \lor (b \not\rightarrow a)$

Comment: That is related to the previous question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition, valid for $a,L \in \mathbb{R}$, seems to be ok.

And also the negation should be ok, note indeed that the if and only if part is out of the statement since it is a part of the definition, that is

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow P$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \neq L \Leftrightarrow \lnot P$$

maybe at the end of the negation (and then also for the definition), following the suggestion by [Fimpellizieri](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173410/fimpellizieri), we could simply take

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \neq L \Leftrightarrow \exists \varepsilon > 0,\ \forall \delta > 0,\ \exists x,\ (0< |x-a|  < \delta), (|f(x) - L| \ge \varepsilon)$$

but it seems to be not essential and equivalent.

Comment: I would not use $\not\Rightarrow$, simply state $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.
Like in $(\exists x)\,P(x)$ meaning 'there is some $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true. More specifically:

$$\exists x \text{ with } 0<|x-a|<\delta,\, |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri that's also more simpler and clear! and what about the if and only if part, do you agree with mine intepretation?

Comment: I think the negated part on the end though would be $ \geq \epsilon$

Comment: Yes, $(A \iff B) \iff (\neg A \iff \neg B)$. The statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: Oops, yes, it should be $\geq \epsilon$!

Comment: ops, yes just a typo for the previous with $\not\Rightarrow$, I fix